# VS2012 -> VS2013 upgrade leaves some of my code no longer compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

My project contains a class thus:

```
struct tweaker
{
    virtual std::ostream& peek(std::ostream&)   const = 0;
    virtual std::ostream& script(std::ostream&) const;
    const char* Name;
};
```

and a function thus:

```
std::ostream& tweaker::script(std::ostream& Os) const
{
    return Os << std::string(Name) << " " << peek(Os) << "; # ";
}
```

This compiled in VS2012, but VS2013 tells me

```
1>environment_variables.cpp(28): error C2678: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(498): could be 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char>> *)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(478): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(const void *)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(458): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(long double)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(438): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(double)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(418): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(float)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(397): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(unsigned __int64)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(377): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(__int64)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(356): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(unsigned long)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(336): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(long)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(316): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(unsigned int)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(291): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(int)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(271): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(unsigned short)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(237): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(short)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(217): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(std::_Bool)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(210): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(std::ios_base &(__cdecl *)(std::ios_base &))'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(203): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char>> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char>> &))'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(197): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &))'
1>          c:\users\guy\documents\game_dev\ggl\environment_variables.h(191): or       'std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &,const ggl::tweaker &)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(699): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const char *)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(746): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,char)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(784): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const char *)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(831): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,char)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(957): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const signed char *)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(964): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,signed char)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(971): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const unsigned char *)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(978): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,unsigned char)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(988): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::ostream>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &&,const _Ty &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::ostream
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream(1026): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const std::error_code &)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>, std::ostream)'
```

I'm guessing that MS is being a little more picky about what it waves through, and I need to offer some disambiguation somewhere.  The obvious fix is

```
std::ostream& tweaker::script(std::ostream& Os) const
{
    Os << std::string(Name) << " ";
    peek(Os);
    return Os << "; # ";
}
```

but that doesn't solve the larger problem.  Any clues?

Comment: As written the code cannot compile because it has no `#include` directives. They're a critical part of any code that uses the standard library.

Comment: OK, I haven't created a perfectly compiling subset of the actual code, but there is a #include <fstream> prior to the class declaration.  I'll go and make absolutely sure and update the post accordingly.
- Ah, it seems I can't download VS2012 express anymore.  I'll offer a different question.

Comment: you can use .c_str() to make it happy